# I want to load a div text content only once with animation without hovering

Tags: css, animation, hover, css-transitions

I wanted to display a div content only one transition while the page loads first time. or if we refresh it then load once again. for that I used below code but it only shows once then there is again color goes to white. I don't want hover effect

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px 250px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: white;
  animation-name: mymove;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    color: white;
  }

  to {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello,</h1>
  <h2>This is Abhishek.</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the last style of the keyframes at 100%, you can use [animation-fill-mode](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.php). In addition, you can set [animation-iteration-count](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.php) to 1 rather than infinity. By the way, I could not detect a hover effect.

Here I have an example of that:

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px 250px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: white;
  animation-name: mymove;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    color: white;
  }

  to {
    color: black;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello,</h1>
  <h2>This is Abhishek.</h2>
</div>
```